# Missing Create GUID in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

> Where can I find Create GUID options in Visual Studio 2017?

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Edition and I'm not finding the Create GUID options from the Tools menu.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33047.create-guid-tool-in-visual-studio.aspx See troubleshoot section.

Comment: @wannadream - Thanks. That helped. Post it as an answer. Will mark yours as an answer

Comment: Just switch to use PowerShell and type `[guid]:NewGuid()`

Comment: @ShayNissel Did you mean `New-Guid`?

Comment: @nam it's actually `[guid]::NewGuid()` but `New-Guid` is way shorter

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please follow troubleshoot section in this documentation.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33047.create-guid-tool-in-visual-studio.aspx

> If the tool does not appear under the Tools menu, click Tools >
>   External Tools (see image above). It may be that the tool was not
>   registered correctly within the IDE. Using the External Tools window,
>   we can add a reference to guidgen.exe.

Comment: For people missing the .exe file the troubleshooter refers to: modify your visual studio installation to include Desktop development with C++. This is what adds the guidgen.exe to your visual studio.

Comment: @Peter-Paul Thanks, I hadn't guidgen.exe in my VS installation folder.

Answer (score 2):

Mine was in `Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0` instead of the `Microsoft Visual Studio`

Under `c:\program files  (x86)` there are several MVS folders and each with a Common7 folder and some with Tools folder.

In one of then `guidgen.exe` is hiding.

Replace the links from Tools -> External Tools -> Create GUID, for example in my case

`c:\program files  (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late but nowadays with the C# REPL built into VS.NET or the numerous online REPLs a new guid is only as far away as a single line of C#:

```
Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Or, better yet. In PowerShell, `New-Guid`.